# Interchanging Integration and Summation for Non-Absolutely Convergent Series

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

I realize this question has been asked quite a few times, but I am still not sure if I completely understand the answers when it comes to my particular question.

I am wondering what justification can be given for the exchange of order of integration and summation for an example such as:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} \int_{0}^{x}{\sin(nt)dt}}$$

where the terms of the series are not always positive nor is the series abslutely convergent.

In general, I am wondering if for arbitrary functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, one can justify the exchange,

$$\sum{f(x)\int{g(x)}} = \int{\sum{f(x)g(x)}}$$

as long as $\sum{|f(x)\int{g(x)}|} < \infty$ and $\int{\sum{|f(x)g(x)|}}< \infty$.  Is this claim correct?

In previous questions regarding the exchange of the order of integration and summation, many answers have provided justification for series of positive terms, or series which are absolutely covnergent.

For the above example the exchange does give the correct answer in both cases.

Namely,

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} \int_{0}^{x}{\sin(nt)dt}} = 
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^2}} -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^{n-1} \cos(nx)}{n^2}} = \frac{x^2}{4}$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} \int_{0}^{x}{\sin(nt)dt}} = \int_{0}^{x}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^{n-1}\sin(nt)}{n}}}dt = \int_{0}^{x}{\frac{x}{2}} = \frac{x^2}{4}$$